# How to create jquery dialog with iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How to Create a JQuery simple dialog, dialog will not be in div on same page, but it should be in iframe. And model dialog should also destroy once popup is closed.

Current issue with jquery dialog is once popup is close, popup html generated stays on page. If you open same popup five times, all those popup stays in html until You reload the page.

So how to achieve these things?

Comment: Iframe inside the dialog ? or dialog inside the iframe ?

Comment: Dialog inside iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="dialog"/>

var dlg = $('#dialog').html('<iframe id="ifrm"></iframe>');
dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); // Clears the html
    }
});
```

But I prefer this another approach. Once you open the dialog for the first time, set a variable to true. Each time you open the dialog check the variable, if it's false, create the dialog, otherwise just open it.

```
var isOpen = false;
$('#someButton').on('click', function(){
  if(!isOpen){
     // Create the dialog
     isOpen = true;
  }else{
     $('#dialog').dialog('open');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var iframe = $('<div><iframe id="iframetestdialog" src=' + url + ' style="border: none;overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;display: block;" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"></iframe>');
    $dialog = iframe.dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: title
    });
```

These is how you can create dialog dynamically. And you should use 'destroy' while closing. Hope this helps.